# How do I remove unwanted space over my signature?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I need merely one line of space over my signature, but as you can see in the screenshot, Outlook automatically adds 3.

Kindly see the screenshots underneath.

[image]

Comment: It is not easy. It involves email templates and so on. It is much better to press supr 2 times before start writting.

Comment: You may want to add VBA as an option. I'm not saying it's possible with VBa but again, you've not said why this is a problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't the way you showed. The only option I found is to create your own [template](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-reuseable-text-blocks-for-email-messages-8fb6c723-c960-4c8c-9790-3e43ddc4b186) and to use it for new and replies etc. I found this annoying and reverted back to signatures but it may be OK for you.

Even better is probably Quick Parts:

1. Create a new email
2. Add the signature exactly as you want
3. Select all the text in the editor
4. Click on Insert and under Quick Parts, save

Now when you create an email, select Insert > Quick Parts and choose the signature.

A very hacky way (for **new** emails) would be to use Auto hot key, and essentially send

1. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>    <kbd>n</kbd>
2. <kbd>tab</kbd>
3. <kbd>tab</kbd>
4. <kbd>tab</kbd>
5. <kbd>tab</kbd>
6. <kbd>delete</kbd>
7. <kbd>delete</kbd>

The above assumes you have To, Cc and Bcc showing (as well as subject field).

Answer (score 4):

You can only remove the spaces that come after your signature, not the spaces before.
Your signature files are located at: `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures`.
There will be 3 files:

```
YourSignature.html
YourSignature.rtf
YourSignature.txt
```

They can be modified and the spaces that comes after the signature removed as already stated above. However even if they don't have spaces before the signature, when you write a new email, the spaces before the signature are added automatically.

The only way I can think of is to try to modify the template `Mail.oft`. But I am not sure If you will be able to remove the spaces from being added before the signature.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I found that my original HTML, which I copied into the signature editor in Outlook, had a

```
<p>With best regards</p>
```

tag as the first tag. That led to an extra blank line in a new message when Outlook inserted the signature. I changed the HTML to begin with

```
With best regards<br/><br/>
```

Visually it looked the same in new mails but now there where no extra blank line in new mails.